# C : Program prints weird stuff in output, after deleting printf from char function

Tags: c, encryption

I was writing a program in c for vignere cipher, when in a function to generate the key as the same length of input name,i encountered a bug where if i remove the "printf" line displaying the length of input string it, prints weird stuff on the sceen, it happens only when i delete that "printf" line from the GenKey() function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *GenKey(char *key, char *source){
    int i=0,j=0;
    char ReturnKey[strlen(source)];

    printf("%d\n",strlen(source));      // THIS LINE HERE CAUSES PROBLEM

    for(i=0;i<strlen(source)-1;i++){
        if(j==strlen(key)){
            j=0;
        }
        ReturnKey[i]=key[j];
        j++;
        }
        return ReturnKey;
}

int main()
{
    int i;
    char name[10000];
    char container[10000];
    char VigKey[]="INFERNO";
    char *NamePtr;
    char *KeyPtr;
    printf("give a name: ");
    fgets(name,10000,stdin);

    char GeneratedKey[strlen(name)];
    KeyPtr=VigKey;
    NamePtr=name;
    strcpy(GeneratedKey,GenKey(KeyPtr,NamePtr));
    printf("%s",GeneratedKey);
}
```

Output(Before deleting that line):

```
give a name: ATTACKATDAWN
13
INFERNOINFER
```

Now i delete that line

```
char *GenKey(char *key, char *source){
    int i=0,j=0;
    char ReturnKey[strlen(source)];

   // NOW I HAVE DELETED THAT LINE

    for(i=0;i<strlen(source)-1;i++){
        if(j==strlen(key)){
            j=0;
        }
        ReturnKey[i]=key[j];
        j++;
        }
        return ReturnKey;
}
```

Output(After deleting that line):

```
give a name: ATTACKATDAWN
INFERNOINFERα╫`
```

Comment: You're returning a pointer to memory that is already released. After a function returned automatic local variables don't exist anymore.

Comment: Turn on compiler warnings.

Answer (score 1):

Try creating the ReturnKey character array on the heap with malloc like this:

```
char *GenKey(char *key, char *source){
    int i=0,j=0;
    char *ReturnKey = malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(source));
    for(i=0;i<strlen(source)-1;i++){
        if(j==strlen(key)){
            j=0;
        }
        ReturnKey[i]=key[j];
        j++;
    }
    return ReturnKey;
}
```

Before when you were creating ReturnKey, you were doing so as a local variable which only lives in the context of that function. Even though you would see your word still there, that was just because it was still in that position in memory but was no longer being referencing by an object.

When you create a dynamic array with a function like malloc, you are creating it on the so called "heap" which doesn't get released when it goes out of scope, this way you can return it from the function (you actually return a pointer to that location in memory).

When using malloc note that the memory IS NOT RELEASED, and thus you must at some point later release it yourself by calling free otherwise you will leak memory.

This is what the full code might look like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *GenKey(char *key, char *source){
    int i=0, j=0;

    // malloc takes the size of the data type * the length
    char *ReturnKey = malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(source));

    for(i=0;i<strlen(source)-1;i++){
        if(j==strlen(key)){
            j=0;
        }
        ReturnKey[i]=key[j];
        j++;
    }
    return ReturnKey;
}

int main()
{
    int i;
    char name[10000];
    char container[10000];
    char VigKey[]="INFERNO";
    char *NamePtr;
    char *KeyPtr;
    printf("give a name: ");
    fgets(name,10000,stdin);

    KeyPtr=VigKey;
    NamePtr=name;
    char *GeneratedKey = GenKey(KeyPtr,NamePtr);
    printf("%s",GeneratedKey);
    free(GeneratedKey);  // IMPORTANT!!!
}
```

Here is a more in depth article on using malloc and free:

https://www.codingunit.com/c-tutorial-the-functions-malloc-and-free

Comment: This answer would really be helpful if it explained what's wrong with the original code and how your change fixes it. Without it this advice does not help anybody here (and effectively will be a memory leak in the OP's application).

Comment: @zerkms ya your right let me edit

Comment:  .............